# Scala Abstract Typing with Tabulate

Tags: scala, scala-breeze, abstract-type

I am trying to make a generic `repVec` function similar to Matlab's `repmat` function using Scala Breeze.

First I tried:

```
def repVec[T](in: DenseVector[T], nRow: Int): DenseMatrix[T] =
{
    DenseMatrix.tabulate[T](nRow, in.size){case (_, j) => in(j)}
}
```

but this gave me the error:

```
Error:(112, 41) No ClassTag available for T
        DenseMatrix.tabulate[T](nRow, in.size){case (_, j) => in(j)}
                                              ^
Error:(112, 41) not enough arguments for method tabulate: (implicit evidence$15: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T], implicit evidence$16: breeze.storage.Zero[T])breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[T].
Unspecified value parameters evidence$15, evidence$16.
        DenseMatrix.tabulate[T](nRow, in.size){case (_, j) => in(j)}
                                          ^
```

After doing some reading, particularily [here](http://engineering.monsanto.com/2015/05/14/implicits-intro/), I tried adding an implicit `TypeTag` like so:

```
def repVec[T](in: DenseVector[T], nRow: Int)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): DenseMatrix[T] =
{
    DenseMatrix.tabulate[T](nRow, in.size){case (_, j) => in(j)}
}
```

But I got the same error.

Any thoughts as to what is going on? How is my usage different than this example (from the link) which I can build just fine?

```
def gratuitousIntermediateMethod[T](list:List[T])(implicit tag :TypeTag[T]) =
    getInnerType(list)

def getInnerType[T](list:List[T])(implicit tag:TypeTag[T]) = tag.tpe.toString
```

**Edit:**

Needed `ClassTag` and `Zero`, here is the full solution:

```
def repVec[T:ClassTag:Zero](in: DenseVector[T], nRow: Int): DenseMatrix[T] =
{
    DenseMatrix.tabulate[T](nRow, in.size)({case (_, j) => in(j)})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an implicit ClassTag, not a TypeTag. They're unrelated types (somewhat frustratingly).

Comment: Hmm, do you main change the implicit bit to `(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]):`?

Comment: Alright I added a `ClassTag` like [so](http://pastebin.com/jhuvuhFf). I am now getting the error: `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type breeze.storage.Zero[T]`. Is this because `DenseMatrix` is restricted to numeric types like `Double`, `Int`, etc?

I noticed this: `@spec(Double, Int, Float, Long) V` in the definition of the `DenseMatrix`, do I need to do something similar?